# How to Iterate the array of json objects(gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm making a ship defense game.
I have a problem with getting the array of waypoints.
The map contains the `JSON` format(Using `GSON`)

```
{
 "waypoints" : {
    "ship": { 
       "first_type": [[0,0],[5,7],[2,8],[4,4],[10,10],[12,0],[0,12],[12,8],[8,8]]                            
    },
    "boat": { 
       "first_type": [[0,0],[5,7],[2,8],[4,4],[10,10],[12,0],[0,12],[12,8],[8,8]]                            
    }
  }
}
```

My code:

```
    jse = new JsonParser().parse(in);
    in.close();

    map_json = jse.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject wayPoints = map_json.getAsJsonObject("waypoints").getAsJsonObject("ship");
```

I wrote this one,but it doesn't work.

```
JsonArray asJsonArray = wayPoints.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray();
```

How can I foreach the array of objects?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simplify your code and retrieve the `first_type` array using the following code. Same code should pretty much work for the `second_type` array as well:

```
JsonArray types = map_json
    .getAsJsonObject("waypoints")
    .getAsJsonObject("ship")
    .getAsJsonArray("first_type";

for(final JsonElement type : types) {
    final JsonArray coords = type.getAsJsonArray():
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`wayPoints` is a JSON object. It contains another JSON object called `ship`. And `ship` contains a JSON array called `first_type`. So you should get the `first_type` array from the `ship` object, and iterate on this array.